# Getting undefine as a returned value

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

I have been working on a code to dynamically add and remove rows, the code works well but Im having problems with my the data it returns, I keep getting undefined but the response on my network is correct don't know whats up but I think it's my jquery. here's my script code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
               url:'<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/ajax/postsic',
               type:'post',
               data:{   'division':$('#div_desc').val(),
                        'majorgroup':$('#mgrp_desc').val(),
                        'group':$('#grp_desc').val(),
                        'sic description':$('#sic_description').val()},       
               success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                 var row = '<tr><td>' + data.majorgroup + '</td><td>' + data["div"] + '</td>';
                 $('#t2').append(row);

              }               

          });

    });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: Your question title is not acceptable. It tells *nothing* about the actual question besides the information already contained in the tags. Please edit it. Also, have you tried debugging the code? If `data` is alert-able (and shows up as something useful) it's not an object with the properties you are looking for.

Comment: if you could post your response

Comment: my response value it shows {"div":"22","mj":"221","g":"2212","sic":"6471","majorgroup":"EXTRACTION OF CRUDE PETROLEUM AND NATURAL GAS; SERVICE ACTIVITIES INCIDENTAL TO OIL AND GAS EXTRACTION, EXCLUDING SURVEYING","group":{},"siccode":{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the datatpe:"json" so that it will know what type of information to echo back and remove the alert line. Final ode below. hope it helps someone too.

```
dataType: "json",
               data:{   'division':$('#div_desc').val(),
                        'majorgroup':$('#mgrp_desc').val(),
                        'group':$('#grp_desc').val(),
                        'sic description':$('#sic_description').val()},       
               success:function(data){
                 var row = '<tr><td>' + data["div"] + '</td><td>' + data.majorgroup + '</td>';
                 $('#t2').append(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `dataType: "json"`

```
$.ajax({
     url:'<?php echo $this->baseURL()?>/ajax/postsic',
     type:'post',
     dataType: "json", //<-----you have missed this
     .......
});
```

---

Not sure but you can try `JSON.parse()`:

```
success:function(data){
    var json = JSON.parse(data);
    var row = '<tr><td>' + json.majorgroup + '</td><td>' + json["div"] + '</td>';
    $('#t2').append(row);
}
```

Comment: It still gives me an undefined value, this is my response value it shows {"div":"22","mj":"221","g":"2212","sic":"6471","majorgroup":"EXTRACTION OF CRUDE PETROLEUM AND NATURAL GAS;  SERVICE ACTIVITIES INCIDENTAL TO OIL AND GAS EXTRACTION, EXCLUDING SURVEYING","group":{},"siccode":{}}

Comment: script not running this time will keep working on it

Comment: Hey got it to work, your datatype:"json" really helped i just neede to remove my alert. Thanks jai